# Does a "capacitor" for light exist?

Tags: capacitance, visible-light, charge

If I have a light that is flickering at a frequency low enough to be perceived by the human eye, is there any type of material that exists that will smooth out the appearance of flickering? Similar to how a capacitor smooths the output of a rectifier?

Comment: @ACuriousMind - duplicate, and by the same author, it appears. Unfortunate consequence of a migration.